# which better way Angular install

Tags: angular

I am new in angular, I know how to install angular with angular cli, also i can include angular with just give angular js link to script tag,My question is that if i can just use script tag to link angular js and start working then why should i use npm angular cli which install too many module, that confusing me simplicity of angular, why make it so complex ? if i can only use it in simple way, because i dont know that lots of node module also i can not skip that without knowing what i am actually using these module..Please dont make it complex i just want simple and clean answer,Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*AngularJS is not Angular.*

Simply put, AngularJS is any version of AngularJS up to ~1.6.X. You include AngularJS in your project by using the script tag, as you put it.

Angular which is Angular 2 through Angular 4 is completely different. Instead of including it in your project, it is designed to be it's own project. It includes the Angular CLI which is by far the fastest way to scaffold your project. Since this method is an entire fully functioning project/Single Page Application(SPA), it's going to have dependencies.  If you want to start from scratch, and with as few dependencies as possible, use the command `ng new my-app --minimal`.

I hope this clarification helps you!

Comment: Can you please also help me to understand how i can integrate bootstrap with angular? as far as i understand angular not for responsive site, i need angular with bootstrap responsive class, thanks.

Comment: Angular is most definitely designed to be responsive! You can either use the regular bootstrap, or you can look into `ng-bootstrap` which is a library that allows you to use bootstrap in native Angular fashion. I've used both, and both are good options.

Comment: Thanks for answer, angular has a class for different device screen size ? i am not clear how angular responsive ! well i want to use something like sm-md-lg this kind of class in angular,what is the way to add regular bootstrap with angular?

Comment: No Angular doesn't have things like controlling the look and feel, that's done with CSS (bootstrap, material-design, and lots more in the works!) Angular's part in 'responsive' has to do with things like responding to mouse clicks or giving immediate feedback for forms.

Answer (score 0):

You can install it manually by hand

You can use the Angular-CLI (Command Line Interface) to install it for you

You can upgrade an Angular 2 project to an Angular 4 project

You can clone an Angular 4 project at Github

I prefer git to install angular

You can download and install Git from http://git-scm.com/download. Once installed, you should have access to the git command line tool. The main commands that you will need to use are:

`git clone` ...: Clone a remote repository onto your local machine.

`git checkout` ...: Check out a particular branch or a tagged version of the code to hack on.

Comment: Thanks but i want to know why i need that lots of npm module ? do i need that for my simple angular project, which module i am using even i dont know !

Comment: If you are developing simple angular application following libraries are required   <script src="angular-aria.min.js"></script>
If you are using routing feature following library is required along with main library <script src="angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>if you are using angular material then <script src="angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-material.min.js"></script> Please learn about which api are used for what  refer following link https://docs.angularjs.org/api

Comment: Thanks , i understand this, this is the simple way, but when i am using npm angular cli they are installing lots of ther module inside node module folder, what is the purpose of that for using anguler ? all that needed or just they give that module for future use ?